# symfony how to translate form error message

Tags: forms, internationalization, symfony1

Does anyone know how to translate form error messages in Symfony ?

At the moment I write this line in the `configure()` of the form:

```php
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('I18N'));
```

And then I overwrite all error messages with the `__()` method.

Is there any way for Symfony to translate error messages without calling a helper and overwriting error messages ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I do it:

Add to the `configure` function of the Form to following line:

`$this->widgetSchema->getFormFormatter()->setTranslationCatalogue('forms');`

Then create a translation file like:
`\i18n\forms.nl.xml`
(in your application root or the plugin root)

It's also possible to add translations for the default validators (like 'Required.', etc.)

Comment: You can also enable i18n to all site by setting *i18n: on* on your app/config/settings.yml. There's no need in overwriting all messages with __() method. Check http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/08-Internationalisation-and-Localisation

Comment: Keep in mind that labels and error messages are translated automatically using the messages catalogue, no configuration is neccesary for this behavior (except the `i18n: on`).

Comment: where is this catalogue ? is it apps/frontend/i18n/messages.fr.xml ?

Comment: In my case it's apps/frontend/i18n/en/messages.xml

Comment: it's refusing to work for me T_T I've tried putting the translation file into both apps/frontend/i18n/en/forms.xml and apps/frontend/i18n/forms.en.xml It only loads from the messages.xml it seems :/